# Importing tensorflow makes python 3.6.5 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Tensorflow used to work on my computer. But now when I try to `import tensorflow` python itself errors out. I am not given a traceback call to tell me what the error  is. I get a window's prompt that says "Python has stopped working". When I click "debug" all I get is "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in python.exe". I've never had a python package actually error out python itself for me, I've always just had a traceback error thrown by python if I didn't install something right.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow (effectively updating from 1.7.0 to 1.12.0) but that has not helped. I'm not sure how to search for a solution to this problem either since I'm not given a traceback or an error code or an error message aside from the very generic one above.

I'm currently using python 3.6.5 with tensorflow 1.12.0 (CPU only) installed. My OS is Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit.

Any ideas?

EDIT: The python distro I am using is through Anaconda and I'm trying to run python directly through the anaconda prompt (command line interface).

EDIT2: I used the `faulthandler` module to see if I can get a stack trace out of it, and I got a `Windows fatal exception: code 0xc0000139` and a  `Windows fatal exception: access violation`, along with a bunch of lines linking to various `frozen importlib._bootstrap` lines of code in various `__init__.py` modules.

EDIT3: For a bit more context, this is on a workplace machine with a lot of security software installed on it.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio for Python?

Comment: I am trying to execute python through the anaconda prompt. I forgot to include this detail. I will do so right away.

Comment: Python modules written in C can crash the interpreter if they segfault. Sounds like what's happening here. My guess is something is wrong with your tensorflow installation- check that you've got the right one for your platform (windows 64 bit) and downgrade to 1.7.0 if that's the last version that worked. It's possible your CPU is no longer supported because the precompiled version you installed includes some optimisations that don't work any more

Comment: @mbatchkarov I will try downgrading, but 1.7.0 used to work and then all of a sudden it didn't, which is why I upgraded.

Comment: I have tried 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.6.0, and 1.12.0 and none of them work. All lead to the same windows error.

Comment: Could you provide the values which are present in your windows path? Do these match with your python installation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved the issue. The following procedure was used to find and fix the problem:

I used the `faulthandler` module to force python to print out a stack trace and recieved a `Windows fatal exception: access violation` error which seems to suggest the problem was indeed a segfault caused by some module used by tensorflow.

I tried to fix dependencies by doing a `conda update --all` and then a `conda clean --all` which didn't fix the problem.

I noticed though that the problems seems to arise from the `h5py` and `keras` modules so I did `pip install --upgrade h5py` and `pip install --upgrade keras` and `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` and the problem was fixed. I am now using `tensorflow version 1.12.0`, `keras version 2.2.4`, and `h5py version 2.8.0`.

The key to solving this problem seems to be the `faulthander` module which showed me which modules (h5py and keras) were leading to the segfault.

Comment: Please, accept the answer you provided, for future users reading the question

Comment: When I installed openCV in my conda environment it somehow downgraded h5py, and started giving me this error. Upgrading h5py fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following Steps

```
conda install -c anaconda qt
conda update qt pyqt
```

start again